# Get All JRadioButton from a ButtonGroup

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, buttongroup

If we consider i have a `ButtonGroup` component, which have two `JRadioButton` like this :

```
JRadioButton bButton = new JRadioButton("Boy");
JRadioButton gButton = new JRadioButton("Girl");
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

bButton.setSelected(true);

group.add(bButton);
group.add(gButton);
```

How can I get all the `JRadioButton` components from the `ButtonGroup` ordered by the default order so I can set the first `JRadioButton` Selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i found the solution, i think there are a way to return `Enumeration<AbstractButton>`, so use it to return all the `JRadioButton` of this `ButtonGroup`

```
//Convert Enumeration to a List
List<AbstractButton> listRadioButton = Collections.list(group.getElements());

//show the list of JRadioButton
for (AbstractButton button : listRadioButton) {
    System.out.println("Next element : " + ((JRadioButton) button).getText());
    System.out.println("Is selectd = " + button.isSelected());
}

//Set the first JRadioButton selected
if(listRadioButton.size() > 0){
    listRadioButton.get(0).setSelected(true);
}
```